# How do I display index of a TreeViewItem within the ItemTemplate xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a TreeView that uses an DataTemplate to customize the appearance of each item contained within the TreeView. Within the DataTemplate, I want to display the index of the relevant item within the Treeview. What is the best way to approach this? Would a specific {Binding Path=""}  allow me to get the index of the item?

My TreeView:

```
 <TreeView Name="_myTreeView"
      ItemsSource="{Binding [SourceCollection]}" 
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource x:ResourceKey=MyTemplate}"
 />
```

My DataTemplate:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
      <Grid Margin="5,5,5,5">
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition/>
              <RowDefinition/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding Path=IconPath}"/>
          <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=Caption}"/>
          <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Path=[SomePath]}"/>
        </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Where **[SourceCollection]** is the source that the Tree draws it data from, and **[SomePath]** is the Binding Path I want to use to display the index of the item within the Tree. I'm open to taking a different approach entirely if my current method is an inadvisable way to achieve this goal.

Comment: Something like this might be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190004/access-wpf-treeview-selected-index-through-a-treeviewitem-object. It is not as clean as a pure xaml solution, but it might get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! One way this could work is that I could define a new field for my TreeViewItems (say 'index') that would be updated for all TreeViewItem each time a TreeViewItem is added to, removed from, or moved within the Tree. This field would contain the current index of that TreeViewItem. Then this field could be simply displayed in the XAML. I could use the method described in the linked article to get the index. My only problem is that this idea seems like it creates extra work; something more elegant would be nice. HTML for example, has ordered lists.Hoping for something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a new property to items in my SourceCollection. This new property stores the index value that I was looking for.

Requirements for this application changed such that a simple integer index was insufficient. Adding a new property was the best way to go here. The index is updated after each change operation on the Tree.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `AlternationCount` to `int.MaxValue` on the `TreeView`, and bind to the `ItemsControl.AlternationIndex` attached property in the template.

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Path=ItemsControl.AlternationIndex}"/>
```

Comment: I was unable to implement this one, but found my own solution. Thanks for the input.